# Minecraft Launcher Crashing

Tags: java, minecraft

I just downloaded Minecraft on Ubuntu 12.04 lts. The launcher opens, but when I click play, it crashes and reopens with this error report.

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Surprise! Haha. Well, this is awkward.

Time: 1/1/14 12:31 PM  
Description: Initializing game

org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Could not init GLX  
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.initDefaultPeerInfo(Native Method)  
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.<init>(LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.java:61)  
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.createPeerInfo(LinuxDisplay.java:818)  
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.DrawableGL.setPixelFormat(DrawableGL.java:61)  
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:846)  
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)  
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)  
    at azi.ad(SourceFile:325)  
    at azi.f(SourceFile:696)  
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:152)  


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --   
Stacktrace:  

    `at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.initDefaultPeerInfo(Native Method)  
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.<init>(LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.java:61)  
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.createPeerInfo(LinuxDisplay.java:818)  
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.DrawableGL.setPixelFormat(DrawableGL.java:61)  
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:846)  
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)  
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)  
    at azi.ad(SourceFile:325)  `

-- Initialization --
Details:  
Stacktrace:  
    `at azi.f(SourceFile:696)  
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:152)`

-- System Details --  
Details:  
    `Minecraft Version: 1.7.4  
    Operating System: Linux (i386) version 3.5.0-23-generic  
    Java Version: 1.6.0_27, Sun Microsystems Inc.  
    Java VM Version: OpenJDK Server VM (mixed mode), Sun Microsystems Inc.  
    Memory: 34158592 bytes (32 MB) / 55836672 bytes (53 MB) up to 477233152 bytes   (455 MB)
    JVM Flags: 1 total; -Xmx512M  
    AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used  
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0  
    Launched Version: 1.7.4  
    LWJGL: 2.9.1  
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.  
    GL Caps:   
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.  
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)  
    Resource Packs: []  
    Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null  
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)  
    Vec3 Pool Size: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null  
    Anisotropic Filtering: Off (1)
```

How can I fix the error?

Answer (score -1):

On Mageia 5 I just installed xrandr and ran it and it fix the problem. I don't know if by running it something was configured. But it works.